# Can I force a page break in HTML printing?

Tags: html, printing, page-break

I'm making a HTML report that is going to be printable, and it has "sections" that should start in a new page.

Is there any way to put something in the HTML/CSS that will signal to the browser that it needs to force a page break (start a new page) at that point?

I don't need this to work in every browser out there, I think I can tell people to use a specific set of browsers in order to print this.

Answer (score 593, accepted):

Add a CSS class called "pagebreak" (or "pb"), like so:

```css
@media print {
    .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; } /* page-break-after works, as well */
}
```

Then add an empty DIV tag ([or any block element that generates a box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after)) where you want the page break.

```html
<div class="pagebreak"> </div>
```

It won't show up on the page, but will break up the page when printing.

P.S. Perhaps this only applies when using `-after` (and also what else you might be doing with other `<div>`s on the page), but I found that I had to augment the CSS class as follows:

```css
@media print {
    .pagebreak {
        clear: both;
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

Comment: But like all good things in CSS, this doesn't always work consistently across the board, so test the living daylights out of it, lest you have angry users wondering why your site prints piles of extra blank pages!

Comment: According to MDN, `page-break-after` "applies to block elements that generate a box," so using an empty `<span>` element won't work. It's a better idea to apply it to a piece of your content. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

Comment: @nullability: Good catch. I had mainly used this at my old job in a WebBrowser control in WinForms which used IE, the gold standard of following standards.

Comment: This did not work for me in Chrome... I'm trying to do a pagebreak inside after a <tr> inside a <table>, will it work in this case ?

Comment: For some reason, when using this trick in Chrome, 1 row of pixels of next page was leaking into previous one (noticeable when using background-color). I fixed it by using `.pagebreak { min-height: 1px; page-break-before: always; }`

Comment: I had same issue. I added <div style='page-break-before: always;'></div> after every 3rd row and my parent div have display: flex; so I removed it and it was working as I want

Comment: Downvoting because this is a 'legacy property'. See answer below (at the time of this message)

Comment: See [CSS Page-Break Not Working in all Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4884380/8068625) for properties that cause issues

Answer (score 61):

```html
First page (scroll down to see the second page)
<div style="break-after:page"></div>
Second page
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="window.print();return false;" />Print (to see the result) </button>
```

Just add this where you need the page to go to the next one (the text "page 1" will be on page 1 and the text "page 2" will be on the second page).

```
First page (this will be on page n.1)
<div style="break-after:page"></div>
Second page (This will be on page n.2)
```

Comment: `<div style="break-after:page"></div>` is what worked for me. The first option didn't work for my particular situation.

Comment: This is because the previous value `always` (of the deprecated `page-break-*` CSS properties) is now equivalent to the value `page` (in the now recommended properties `break-before` and `break-after`) ; see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after#page_break_aliases

Answer (score 59):

Try this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_print_pagebb.asp)

```
<style>
@media print
{
h1 {page-break-before:always}
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you want to skip the first header on the first page, try `h1:not(:first-child) { page-break-before:always; }`

Answer (score 33):

Just wanted to put an update. `page-break-after` is a legacy property now.

Official [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) states

> This property has been replaced by the [break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after) property.

**Update:** Based on recent comments.

[**Page break aliases**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after#page_break_aliases)

For compatibility reasons, the legacy page-break-after property should be treated by browsers as an alias of break-after. This ensures that sites using page-break-after continue to work as designed. A subset of values should be aliased as follows:

```
page-break-after    break-after
auto                auto
left                left
right               right
avoid               avoid
always              page
```

> **Note:** The always value of page-break-* was implemented by browsers as
> a page break, and not as a column break. Therefore the aliasing is to
> page, rather than the always value in the Level 4 spec.

Comment: It should be noted that this property is only supported by Microsoft IE and Edge browsers. https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_break-after_paged_context_always

Comment: [The link by  @Benjamin states today](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_break-after_paged_context_always), that `break-after` is supported by latest Microsoft IE `10`-`11`, older Edge `12`-`18` and Firefox (`65`-`113`) browsers. It seems **un**supported by Chrome (`4`-`114`), most Opera except `11.5`, current MS Edge `79`-`111`, IE `6`-`9` and Safari (`3.1`-`16.5`). Can somebody confirm or update these info? That looks like pretty bad support IMHO.

Comment: @Cadoiz It's specifically `always` that's unsupported. It should be `break-after: page` instead https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_break-after_paged_context_page

Answer (score 15):

You can use the CSS property [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) (or `page-break-after`). Just set `page-break-before: always` on those block-level elements (e.g., heading, `div`, `p`, or `table` elements) that should start on a new line.

For example, to cause a line break before any 2nd level heading and before any element in class `newpage` (e.g., `<div class=newpage>`...), you would use

```
h2, .newpage { page-break-before: always }
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this (its work in Chrome, Firefox and IE):

```
... content in page 1 ...
<p style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="page-break-before: always;">&nbsp;</p>
... content in page 2 ...
```

Answer (score 8):

**For example**:
below code is present at end of the page and you want to force HTML to print on another page so you can code like this

```
       <table>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td width="180" valign="top">
                            <p>
                                <strong> </strong>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <strong> </strong>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <strong> </strong>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <strong> </strong>
                            </p>
                            <p align="center">
                                <strong>Approved by Director</strong>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**the main code gose here: desired answer**

```
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid;page-break-after:always"></div>
```

Now write the remaining code for the second/another page like this

```
                <table border="1">
                            <tr class="center">
                                <td>
                                    #Main<b>&nbsp;Main</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    #Project<b>&nbsp;Project</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    #TypeMainProj<b>&nbsp;Main + Project</b>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    #Imprest<b>&nbsp;Imprest</b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Below code worked for  me and  there are some more examples [Here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/html+page+break)

```
  <div style="page-break-inside:avoid;page-break-after:always">
  </div>
```

Comment: `page-break-after:always` always gives a new black page after the current page. It is empty. `page-break-inside:avoid` worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a blog with articles like this:

```
<div class="article"> ... </div>
```

Just adding this to the CSS worked for me:

```
@media print {
  .article { page-break-after: always; }
}
```

(tested and working on Chrome 69 and Firefox 62).

Reference:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after ; important note: here it's said `This property has been replaced by the break-after property.` but it didn't work for me with `break-after`. Also the MDN doc about `break-after` doesn't seem to be specific for page-breaks, so I prefer keeping the (working) `page-break-after: always;`.

Answer (score 2):

I needed a page break after every 3rd row while we use print command on browser.

I added

```
<div style='page-break-before: always;'></div>
```

after every 3rd row and my parent div have `display: flex;`
so I removed `display: flex;` and it was working as I want.

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
@media print {
  .pagebreak { 
     page-break-before: always; 
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling this for some time, it never worked.

In the end, the solution was to put a style element in the head.

The page-break-after can't be in a linked CSS file, it must be in the HTML itself.

Comment: in the `<style>` head in the html or it should be inline in the element you want the `page-break-after` applied.

Answer (score 0):

> - We can add a *page break* tag with style "*page-break-after: always*" at the point where we want to introduce the pagebreak in the
>     html page.
> - "*page-break-before*" also works

Example:

```
HTML_BLOCK_1
<p style="page-break-after: always"></p>
HTML_BLOCK_2
<p style="page-break-after: always"></p>
HTML_BLOCK_3
```

While printing the html file with the above code, the print preview will show three pages (one for each html block "*HTML_BLOCK_n*" ) where as in the browser all the three blocks appear sequentially one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm printing fixed-size images on all the pages. I am printing ID cards automatically. The solution for me is to define a fixed-size page that holds the fixed-size ID card image. Setting display: flex is part of my solution.

When you place fixed-size items where each item fits exactly with the size of the page, the page breaks consistently during printing.

Answer (score -7):

@[Chris Doggett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-jump-in-html-printing/1664058#1664058) makes perfect sense.
Although, I found one funny trick on [lvsys.com](https://www.lvsys.com/how-to-add-page-breaks-to-html-in-articles), and it actually works on firefox and chrome. Just put this comment anywhere you want the page-break to be inserted. You can also replace the `<p>` tag with any block element.

```
<p><!-- pagebreak --></p>
```