# CSS Page-Break Not Working in all Browsers

Tags: css, page-break

I'm having trouble getting this working in most browsers, except for IE (it even works correctly in IE6) and Opera.

Firefox separates the divs correctly but only prints the first page.

Chrome and Safari only applies the page break to the last div.

How can I get this working across all browsers correctly?

The HTML:

```
<div id="leftNav">
  <ul>
    <!--links etc-->
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainBody">
 <div id="container">
  <div class="pageBreak">
   <!--content-->
  </div>
  <div class="pageBreak">
   <!--content-->
  </div>
  <div class="pageBreak">
   <!--content-->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The divs with the IDs `#leftNav` and `#mainBody` are are set to `float:left`, so they display nicely.

I only want to print the `.pageBreak` classes, hiding the `#leftNav` and the rest of the `#mainBody` with CSS.

The CSS:

```
@media print
{
 #leftNav
 {
  display:none;
 }
 #mainBody
 {
  border:none;
  margin:none;
  padding:none;
 }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know that property should work in all major browsers if you use the "always" value. Could you post your relevant css and html?

Comment: If you've solved the problem yourself and it doesn't happen to be one of the answers below, it would be a good idea to post it here for posterities sake, instead of appending `[solved]` to your question's title (which doesn't do anything really). Also note that SitePoint reference (which sepehr linked to below) is a much better reference for CSS and HTML [than W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: This was one of my first posts and force of habit made me change the title as per many forum rules instead of making a new post. I did visit SitePoint regarding this issue but that didn't give me the help I needed. In this case W3Schools did.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Parent elements can not have `float` on them.

Setting `float:none` on all parent elements makes `page-break-before:always` work correctly.

Other things that can break `page-break` are:

- using `page-break` inside tables
- floating elements
- `inline-block` elements
- block elements with borders

Comment: Which browsers have problems with `inline-block`-elements?

Comment: The last statement of your answer is very important... I had to cut my `<table>` in many parts and set different fixed size on every single columns so the said columns would not adjust to the content and still look great. I now wish to destroy every single printer in the world... Thanks for the clarifications

Comment: Also `display: flex;` will break it.  At least in my experience in Chrome :)

Comment: As well make sure your element isn't hidden. I had that problem once when I wanted to place page breaks on elements with specific content in it. So I set them to hidden and added a page break on the same element which did not work.

Comment: For me it, there was a parent container with an inline-block. Updated that to block instead. It works!~ You could test this by using Ctrl + P in Chrome

Answer (score 34):

For the sake of completion, and for the benefit of others who are having the same problem, I just want to add that I also had to add `overflow: visible` to the body tag in order for FireFox to obey the page breaks and even to print more than just the first page.

Comment: For a bit more completeness, `display:flex` seems to mess things up as well.

Comment: @Rajesh did that affect Chrome too for you? Or just Firefox?

Comment: In Firefox print display:flex messed up, put display:block in print.css

Comment: Sometimes, IE rather requires an `overflow: hidden`to make `break-inside: avoid` work correctly.

Comment: `@media print{  body{    overflow:visible;  } }` fixed my problem, thank you!

Comment: @Ben it works like a charm, in my case, I print apart of HTML.

Comment: Adding overflow:visible to my body el helped in Edge as well.

Answer (score 24):

I've found that Twitter Bootstrap classes add a bunch of stuff to the page which has made it difficult to get page-breaks working. Firefox worked right away, but I've had to follow various suggestions to get it to work in Chrome and, finally, IE (11).

I followed the suggestions here and elsewhere. The only property I "discovered" that I haven't seen yet mentioned is "box-sizing". Bootstrap can set this property to "box-sizing: border-box", which broke IE. An IE-friendly setting is "box-sizing: content-box". I was led to this by the caveat about "block elements with borders" made by Richard Parnaby-King https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314590/3397752.

It looks like it's a bit of an arms race to discover the next property that might break page-breaks.

This is the setting that worked for me (Chrome, FF, IE 11). Basically, it tries to override all the problematic settings on all divs on the printed page. Of course, this might also break your formatting, and that would mean that you'll have to find another way to set up the page.

```
@media print {

    div { float: none !important; position: static !important; display: inline; 
          box-sizing: content-box !important;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you i add  display: inline !important; and margin : 0 !important  too

Answer (score 11):

There is a solution if the parent has float . For the element to which you applied the page-break, make the element overflow:hidden. Thats all. It worked for me.

```
<div style='float:left'>

<p style='overflow:hidden;page-break-before:always;'></p>

</div>
```

Comment: This worked OK, for me using `wkhtmltopdf` I needed to set `html, body { overflow: hidden; }` because a template .css was using `overflow-x:hidden`. This shouldn't be downvoted. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Although this is not prominently documented, it should be noted that the page-break properties cannot be applied to table elements. If you have any elements that have a `display: table;` or `display:table-cell;` applied to them (common in many templates under the clearfix class) then contained elements will ignore the page-break rules. Just cancel out the the rule in your print stylesheet and you should be OK (after the floats have also been removed, of course).

Here is an example of how to do this for the popular clearfix problem.

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after{  
    display: block!important;
}
```

The other place I have run into this is when the template declared the entire page (usually called main or main wrapper) with `display:inline-block;`

If the section is inside of an inline-block, it will not work so keep your eyes open for those as well. Changing or overwriting `display:inline-block;` with `display:block` should work.

Answer (score 8):

I had a `position: absolute;` in the div printing that caused this not to work.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the parent element has `display:block;` rather than `display: flex;`. This helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 6):

["Firefox versions up to and including 3.5 don’t support the avoid, left, or right values."](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-before)
IE support is also partial
you can achieve what needed by :page-break-before:always;  which is supported in all browsers
"but only print the first page"  : I don't think it is css related , I suppose it's sth on print window of browser :)

Answer (score 5):

what's your code?

like this?:

```
<style>
@media print
{
table {page-break-after:always}
}
@media print
{
table {page-break-before:always}
}
</style>
```