# Applying "page-break-before" to a table row (tr)

Tags: css, page-break

According to W3.org, the style `page-break-after` applies to block level elements (http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-CSS21-20040225/page.html#page-break-props)

`<tr>` is a block level element (according to this: http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html, it is)

I'm doing this, but the page break is not creating an actual page break when printing:

```
  <table>
    <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
    <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
    <tr style="page-break-after: always"><td>blah</td></tr>
    <tr><td>blah</td></tr>
  </table>
```

**Am I doing this the correct way?**

If `<tr>` wasn't a block level element: **how am I suppose to achieve this page break?**

Note: the before code is just an example, but what I'm trying to do is to put a page-break every 5 rows of the table, so if you know any tips for that case, will be appreciated

Comment: Print functions are poorly implemented in browsers; you get all kinds of incompatibility. If you're building the table programmatically, I'd suggest cutting it up into smaller tables, 5 rows each, and put page breaks between them.

Comment: Cutting it up into smaller tables would be kind of visible in the "html version" (before printing) :(

Comment: Then cut them up only when printing...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside `<head>`, set this style in your CSS stylesheet

```
<head>
    <style>
        @media print {
            tr.page-break  { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
        }   
    </style>
</head>
```

That way, it will produce a page break during printing right before this table row.

```
<tr class="page-break">
</tr>
```

Comment: Additionally (to prevent ugly tds, because of a tr which is display block) I inserted an empty tr with class 'page-break' and height = 0.

Comment: You can also use a pseudo-element to avoid the need for the empty tr:  `@media print {
  tr.page-break:before { 
    content:""; 
    display: block; page-break-before: always;
  }
}`

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to work or change anything, at least not in Chrome 50-something.

Comment: Works in Firefox (with no need to set <tr> to display: block). Doesn't work in Chrome or Opera.

Comment: checked, doesn't work on the latest firefox or chrome

Answer (score 2):

[The site you referenced](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) states that `<tr>` "**may also be** considered a block-level element since it **may contain** block-level elements." Neither the [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html) or [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) state that `<tr>` is a block-level element.

**Some Possible Solutions**

1. Based on the wording and your example, I would ensure that the cell contains a true block-level element. Here are two examples using `<h1>` and `<p>` which are block-level text elements.

   ```
   <tr style="page-break-after: always"><td><h1>Next Section</h1></td></tr>
   <tr style="page-break-after: always"><td><p>This will be a new page.</p></td></tr>
   ```
2. Others have reported similar problems and one of the solutions might work for you.

   - [How to apply CSS page-break to print a table with lots of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712677/how-to-apply-css-page-break-to-print-a-table-with-lots-of-rows)
   - [Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)
   - [Printing a Gridview - how to print n rows on each page using page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029900/printing-a-gridview-how-to-print-n-rows-on-each-page-using-page-break)
   - [page-break-inside doesn't work in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706504/page-break-inside-doesnt-work-in-chrome)
3. As mentioned by [My Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister), you could [attempt to catch the printing action](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20catch%20print%20event) or generate a print version of the page that would separate the table out so you can obtain the desired page break after every five rows.

Answer (score 1):

Set all `<tr>` tags with `display:block` and define the page format and the size in mm for the table and cells.

Here `<td>` tag width is set to 23mm as there are 10 td tag with 2mm padding each side (23+2+2)*10=270 which is `<table>` width.

You can adjust `word-break` depending on how you want to break the words.

```
@media print {

    @page {
        size:A4 landscape;
        margin: 5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm;
        padding: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
    }
    .table{
        width:270mm;
        min-width:270mm;
    }
    td, th{
        padding: 2mm 2mm 2mm 2mm !important;
        display: table-cell;
        word-break:break-all;
        width:23mm;
        min-width:23mm;
    }
    tr{
       display:block;
    }
    tr.page-break  { 
       page-break-before: always; 
    }
}
```