# Couldn't apply pagebreak

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break

I have a list of Months which I want to show one per page while printing, so I thought of using page breaks but the issue is I couldn't apply page breaks. I have also tried putting `<div class="pagebreak"></div>` but I don't understand why it isn't taking effect. Here is my code:

```css
.pagebreak{
  page-break-after: always;
  }
```

```html
<table class="fc-year-main-table fc-border-separate">
    <tr>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-first"></td>
        <td class="fc-year-monthly-td" style="">
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-name fc-first"><a name="201401" data-year="2014" data-month="0" href="#">January</a></div>
            <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="fc-year-month-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-year-week-days"></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-day-grid-container">
                <div class="fc-day-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-footer"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-last"></td>

    <tr class="pagebreak">
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-first"></td>
        <td class="fc-year-monthly-td" style="">
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-name"><a name="201402" data-year="2014" data-month="1" href="#">February</a></div>
            <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="fc-year-month-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-year-week-days"></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-day-grid-container">
                <div class="fc-day-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-footer"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-last"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="pagebreak">
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-first"></td>
        <td class="fc-year-monthly-td" style="">
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-name"><a name="201403" data-year="2014" data-month="2" href="#">March</a></div>
            <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="fc-year-month-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-year-week-days"></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-day-grid-container">
                <div class="fc-day-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-footer"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-last"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="pagebreak">
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-first"></td>
        <td class="fc-year-monthly-td" style="">
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-name"><a name="201404" data-year="2014" data-month="3" href="#">April</a></div>
            <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="fc-year-month-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-year-week-days"></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-day-grid-container">
                <div class="fc-day-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-footer"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-last"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `<tr>` had no `pagebreak` class and  its `</tr>` missing, apart from those issues (fixed them) it works using

```
@media print {
    tr.pagebreak  { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

Seems like `pagebreak` in `tr` is a bit tricky, check this question [Applying "page-break-before" to a table row (tr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481039/applying-page-break-before-to-a-table-row-tr)

Working demo:

```js
window.print();
```

```css
        @media print {
            tr.pagebreak  { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
        }
```

```html
<table class="fc-year-main-table fc-border-separate">
    <tr class="pagebreak">
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-first"></td>
        <td class="fc-year-monthly-td" style="">
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-name fc-first"><a name="201401" data-year="2014" data-month="0" href="#">January</a></div>
            <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="fc-year-month-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-year-week-days"></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-day-grid-container">
                <div class="fc-day-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-footer"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-last"></td>
 </tr>
    <tr class="pagebreak">
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-first"></td>
        <td class="fc-year-monthly-td" style="">
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-name"><a name="201402" data-year="2014" data-month="1" href="#">February</a></div>
            <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="fc-year-month-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-year-week-days"></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-day-grid-container">
                <div class="fc-day-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-footer"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-last"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="pagebreak">
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-first"></td>
        <td class="fc-year-monthly-td" style="">
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-name"><a name="201403" data-year="2014" data-month="2" href="#">March</a></div>
            <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="fc-year-month-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-year-week-days"></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-day-grid-container">
                <div class="fc-day-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-footer"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-last"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="pagebreak">
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-first"></td>
        <td class="fc-year-monthly-td" style="">
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-name"><a name="201404" data-year="2014" data-month="3" href="#">April</a></div>
            <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="fc-year-month-header">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="fc-year-week-days"></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-day-grid-container">
                <div class="fc-day-grid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-year-monthly-footer"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="fc-year-month-border fc-last"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```