# How to force a page break inside an html table when printing (cross-browser)

Tags: printing, html-table, page-break

I have a table and I want to force a page break at a specific `<tr>` element. So, this is the basic table setup:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr> </tr>
<tr>
<td><p>test text before break</p></td>
</tr>
<tr class="page-break"> </tr>
<tr>
<td><p>test text after break</p></td>
</tr>
<tr> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And for css styling:

```
@media print {
.page-break { 
    page-break-before: always; 
    break-before: always; 
}
}
```

Note that `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` have apparently been replaced by `break-before` and `break-after` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55956263/1544609)). I included both in the css example here to make sure all browsers are compatible (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_break-before.asp) for browser compatibilities).

Now, the above table and css works in Firefox; does exactly what is expected and places a page break before the `<tr>` element. BUT, it does nothing in Chrome or Opera (haven't tested other browsers yet).

There have been some discussions on this subject on stackoverflow (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481039/applying-page-break-before-to-a-table-row-tr), for example), but most are outdated and the checked solutions there also don't work in Chrome or Opera. For instance, changing the `<tr>` element to `display: block` has no impact (Firefox adds the page break whether the `<tr>` element is a block or not, and Chrome or Opera do nothing whether or not it is a block).

So I want to start this discussion anew in 2020 to try to find a proper cross-browser solution. So far I haven't been able to find any solution to force a page break within a table that works with Chrome and Opera. Would also like to verify what works in Safari, Edge, etc.