# Get TR break in table in Flying Saucer / Itext

Tags: css, itext, flying-saucer

I have a long table that starts on one page and finishes on another page. The issue is that tr row between these pages does not break, but it stretches. I want the following behavior: If tr can`t fit, the complete row (ALL TR, not a part) should go to the other page

[image: Image of problem]

I have tried these but not work for me

```css
/*.tableAdditionalInfo >table{
    !*-fs-table-paginate: paginate;
    border-collapse: separate;*!
    !*page-break-inside: avoid;*!
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}*/
.tableAdditionalInfo > tr {
    /* page-break-before: always; */
    page-break-after: always
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you seen  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481039/applying-page-break-before-to-a-table-row-tr?

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
    tr {page-break-inside: avoid}
```

Comment: It works for me (I prefer table)

Comment: This works when rowspan is not used. In my case for every rowspan section we have decided to wrap them with tbody tag and set "page-break-inside: avoid" on it. And it started to work as expected.