# Avoid page-break after specific tr row

Tags: html, css, printing, css-print

First of all, I found no duplicate of this, since the problem is not trying to avoid the break inside a row (this already works well) and I am not allowed to repeat headers on the next page.

Misc. threads that did not help with the problem but are related :

- [How to prevent line breaks in list items using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383143/how-to-prevent-line-breaks-in-list-items-using-css)
- [Applying "page-break-before" to a table row (tr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481039/applying-page-break-before-to-a-table-row-tr)
- [Google Chrome Printing Page Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630819/google-chrome-printing-page-breaks)
- [Printing a Gridview - how to print n rows on each page using page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029900/printing-a-gridview-how-to-print-n-rows-on-each-page-using-page-break)

I am printing a table on a PDF, and I want my table to print on the first page if and only if it has at least two rows displayed. If there is not enough space for 2 rows, I want the whole table to move to the next page.

In order to achieve that, I tried to apply a :

```
page-break-after: avoid;
```

to my first `<tr>` tag. The idea being to forbid breaks between first and second row so they are always together. But this does not seem to work.

How can I achieve this behavior ? Is this the right approach and/or are there others ?

**update:** Also tried to declare the `<tr>` as a block in CSS, but still no dice. Then tried to insert a "linker" `<tr>`, displayed as a block, between row 1 and row 2 with :

```
page-break-after: avoid;
page-break-before: avoid;
```

but still not working.