# page-break-after: avoid works only in IE?

Tags: html, css, printing

I am unable to get this CSS to work in Chrome & Firefox.

```
p { page-break-inside: avoid; }
h1 { page-break-after: avoid; }
```

Html:

```
<h1>FOO</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<h1>FOO</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
[..]
```

Chrome & Firefox will insert a page break after the `<h1>` element when printing.

Only IE keeps h1+p together.

The HTML is generated (by https://github.com/chjj/marked) so I'd rather like to solve this by CSS if possible.

- JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QCvA5/86/
- Output: http://jsfiddle.net/QCvA5/86/show/

Comment: check http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303178/page-break-doesnt-work-on-google-chrome

Comment: @NoobEditor thanks - I've seen those links before but none offer a workaround for this case.

Comment: m afraid its not widely supported yet....

Comment: @laktak - did you ever find a solution for this?  Running into the same issue and nothing I dig up online helps.

Comment: @Steve - no, I switched technologies for my markdown conversion to pandoc

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`-webkit-break-after: avoid; -webkit-break-inside: avoid;`

Comment: Chrome doesn't know those (unknown property).