# page-break-after not working in flexboxes

Tags: css, firefox, printing, flexbox, page-break

This doesn't produce the expected result inside print preview in Firefox:

```
<aside>
  side
</aside>

<div>
  <p> page 1 </p>
  <p> page 2 </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  display: flex;
}

aside{
  flex: none;
  width: 100px;
}

div{
  flex: auto;
}

p{
  break-after: always;
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

In Chrome and IE I get 2 pages like I should. It appears that FF doesn't break the div in 2 pages when an ancestor is a flex box. Why?

Comment: this is still an issue in FF as of 2017/08. This might get fixed with `break-after` which, however, is not  implemented in any of the browsers yet.

Answer (score 22):

I'm pretty sure that won't work in firefox.

Things that can break page-break are(using page-break inside)

- tables
- floating elements
- inline-block elements
- block elements with borders

> To define if a break must be done, the following rules are applied:
>
> 1.If any of the three concerned values is a forced break value, that is
>   always, left, right, page, column or region, it has precedence. If
>   several of the concerned values is such a break, the one of the
>   element that appears the latest in the flow is taken (that is the
>   break-before value has precedence over the break-after value, which
>   itself has precedence over the break-inside value).
>
> 2.If any of the
>   three concerned values is an avoid break value, that is avoid,
>   avoid-page, avoid-region, avoid-column, no such break will be applied
>   at that point.
>
> Once forced breaks have been applied, soft breaks may be added if
>   needed, but not on element boundaries that resolve in a corresponding
>   avoid value.

[break after - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after)

In short words, in your case cause you are using it inside `flex` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox doesn't do page-break correctly even with float elements, so I'm not surprised that flex doesn't work. Source: [CSS Page-Break Not Working in all Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884380/css-page-break-not-working-in-all-browsers)

In general, Firefox page-break support isn't great. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after

If you need consistent, cross-browser printing results, the answer is almost always to use server-side PDF generation, with a tool like wkhtmltopdf or princexml.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: flex;
```

is a property that is not, by default, cross browser compatible.

it would be helpful if you had a fiddle for an example or elaborated a bit more on what you're trying to achieve, but I think this will work:

```
display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
display: -moz-box;/* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works)*/
display: -ms-flexbox;/* TWEENER - IE 10 */
display: -webkit-flex;/* NEW - Chrome */
display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

Answer (score -7):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/yejxaq6h/5/