# Flexbox wkhtmltopdf Rendering Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, wkhtmltopdf

I have a page that I am turning into a pdf with wkhtmltopdf. I have a 3 column layout and it works well in Chrome but the pdf is incorrectly generated. Is there an alternative to flexbox that would give the same view or a way to make flexbox work in wkhtmltopdf? Modernizr did not help. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div id="name" class="center">
    <h2>
      Centered Text
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="links" class="left">
    <h3>
    Left Line 1
    <br>
    Left Line 2
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="contact" class="right">
    <h3>
    Right Line 1
    <br>
    Right Line 2
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
</div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.center {
  order: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  order: 1;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  order: 3;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.clear:before,
.clear:after {
  flex-basis: 0;
  order: 1;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Try to use Media query for print view.

Answer (score 15):

`wkhtmltopdf` [uses an old version of WebKit](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1522) and so you must use [the original Flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/), which is nowhere near as powerful but can still do *some* of the same effects.

Note, also, that you'll have to prefix lots of properties with `-webkit-`.

Comment: See also https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1522 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036663/page-break-after-not-working-in-flexboxes.  I'm using css-next and setting `Chrome >= 13` worked for me.

Comment: Can someone tell me why it uses an old version of WebKit?  I keep seeing the reason that nothing works right is because of this, but no one says why it is an old version.

Comment: @Arrow_Raider - Mostly because WebKit is abandoned, so there really isn't a proper current version to use.  While lots of other things are derived from WebKit, they use forks, not the original QtWebKit, which is what wkhtmltopdf is based on.

See https://wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html for the full story.

Answer (score 4):

This specific comment in that issue brings a solution that worked for me: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1522#issuecomment-848651693

"to make work flex on wkhtmltopdf you need to use display: -webkit-box; for flex and -webkit-box-pack: justify; for justify-content: space-between;. So we should use old flex syntax"

Answer (score 1):

EDIT after comment from Ying-Shan Lin:
As pointed out by TALlama, wkhtmltopdf uses an old version of WebKit.

I found [this page](http://www.cssdrive.com/cssautoprefixer/) that adds prefixes to you CSS and make it compatible with older versions of WebKit and other browser's engines.

Your code with CSS prefixes would be as follows:

```
.header {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.center {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
      -ms-flex-order: 2;
          order: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
      -ms-flex-order: 3;
          order: 3;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.clear:before,
.clear:after {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
      flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

If the link becomes invalid, I just found it searching for "CSS autoprefixer" in Google, there you can find more options.

Note: This does not apply to your code, but it's worth to mention that I still encountered some problems with `display:grid`, so other people are aware of it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32472113)

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick for me and successfully converted 90% of the CSS