# Using align-items with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, css, flexbox, webkit, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert a HTML to PDF. I know wkhtmltopdf uses an old version of webkit, which makes things a little more complicated.

I have a contact image and I want to display the contact name right next to it:

[Image: How it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEsb2.png)

**This is my HTML:**

```
<div class="contact">
    <img src="C:/mypath/picture.jpg">
    <span>Contact Name</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.contact {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: left;
}

div.contact>img {
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

div.contact>span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
}
```

Doesn't work so far. Applying `align-items: center;` to `div.contact` doesn't work either.

Comment: hi. look it, pls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784813/flexbox-wkhtmltopdf-rendering-issue

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @s.kuznetsov! I've already checked it though and it didn't help because it does not explain how to center elements vertically. The original Flexbox spec didn't get me further either ...

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your solution. Actually **align-self** is working but **.contact** height is not big enough to cover viewport. So I wrote this; I hope it's enough for you.

For HTML

```html
<div class="contact">
    <div class="contact-box">
        <img src="C:/mypath/picture.jpg">
        <span>Contact Name</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for CSS

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.contact {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}

.contact-box {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.contact img {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.contact span {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

align-items doesn't work with wkhtmltopdf, but **-webkit-box-align: center** do work, use it with **display: -webkit-box**

```
div.contact {
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-align: center;
}
```