# flask pdfkit not rendering uikit

Tags: flask, uikit, jinja2, wkhtmltopdf

I apologize for the long post in advance...I just hope that some of the information included in my question might be helpful for someone else.

I have been trying to print a PDF from an html page rendered in Flask.
This PDF contains several feature that I would like to include in the PDF such as `Jinja2` templating variables inline `css` and static files, `javascript` libraries like `momentjs` and `UIKit`, and some images.

I have been successful in putting together the majority of these pieces but it seems that I can't find any solution for 2 features: the `UIKit` `javascript` library some inline CSS.

here a simplified version of the ecosystem:
I define the absolute path `base` that I  send to `Jinja2` to correctly include the `JS` static libraries (including `momentjs`) and render the html. After defining some options for `wkhtmltopdf`, I prepare the array a static `css` files (`uikit.min.css` amongst others) that I use to style the PDF, and I send the pdf as a response to the browser.

```py
def generatePdf():
    ## missing text ##
    base = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

    document = render_template('to_be_printed.html', base=base, order=res) # order is variable for Jinja2 - not relevant
    options = {
        'page-size': 'A4',
        'enable-local-file-access': None, # to avoid blanks
        'javascript-delay': 1000,
        'no-stop-slow-scripts': None,
        'debug-javascript': None,
        'enable-javascript': None
    }

    css = assets.bundles['home_css'].urls()
    css = [base+path for path in css]
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(document, False, options=options, verbose=True, css=css)
  
    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    return response
```

In this version of the file there are all the element that I am trying to render in  `to_be_printed.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style media="screen">
      html, body {
        background: #fff
      }
      .navigation {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Reservation N. {{ order }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navigation uk-flex uk-flex-between uk-flex-bottom" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row">
       <div class="">
         <h2 class="uk-margin-remove" style="color:red">Hello {{order.from_data.strftime('%d %B %Y at %H:%M') }}</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="uk-logo">
         <a class="uk-logo" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">
           <img class="" src="{{ order.logo }}" alt="Database X" style="max-width: 350px; width: 70%">
         </a>
         <p id="io">doesn't matter</p>
       </div>
     </div>
     {% assets "home_js" %}
       <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ base_url+ASSET_URL }}"></script>
     {% endassets %}
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var el = document.getElementById('io')
      el.style.color = 'red'
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- All the `CSS` files sent as `css` parameter through `pdfkit.from_string` are perfectly applied.
- In the header the style for `html, body` is working but I cannot display the `div.navigation` as flex. I am trying it from

  - the `<head>`,
  - inline from UIKit `class='uk-flex'` and
  - manually `style='display:flex`,
    although the inline style `<h2 style="color:red">` is working fine.
- All the `jinja2` variables are rendered fine, but I had to call the `strftime` because formatting inline with `moment` (loaded at the end of the document) using `moment(order.from_date).format()` didn't work.
- a simple handwritten script at the bottom of the page is working fine (so `javascript` is actually running on the template).

The problems seems to be different, but everything would work if I manage to load and apply the `UIKit javascript library` (not sure about the `flex` though). I tried a lot of different options for pdfkit, but no changes seems to affect this behaviour:

- `'javascript-delay': 1000,` I even set it to 50000...no changes
- `'no-stop-slow-scripts': None,` does not affect
- `'debug-javascript': None,` helped me a lot, but now there are no error/warning/logs
- `'enable-javascript': None` does not affect

I also moved the script before the body (inside and outside the `<head>`.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not UIKit at all. The incompatibility is due to the fact that wkhtmltopdf uses an old version of UIKit as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236447/8010921).

Which means that in order to create a flex element you should use the  non-standard `-webkit-box-flex` CSS property in place of the `uk-flex` class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).