# New page from HTML in kartik\mpdf (Yii2)

Tags: pdf, yii2, pdf-generation, mpdf

I have a problem. How to add a new page from HTML to PDF?

Immediately I will say that I do not know why, but solutions such as:

```
<pagebreak />
```

or

```
h1 {page-break-before: always}
```

not working.

My PHP Code:

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_FILE,
    'filename' => $path,
    'content' => $content,
    'cssInline' => '.font_next{font-family:DoodlePen}table{border-collapse:collapse;width:100%}td{border:1px solid #000}',
]);
return $pdf->render();
```

Does anyone have this experience and can help you?

Comment: Could you provide a HTML/PHP code sample?

Comment: Sure. I put the code above. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it works.

I  use this method: https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

In HTML:

```
<div className="page-break"></div>
```

In PHP:

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_FILE,
    'filename' => $path,
    'content' => $content,
    'cssInline' => '
        @media all{
            .font_next{font-family:DoodlePen}table{border-collapse:collapse;width:100%}td{border:1px solid #000}.page-break {display: none;}
        }
        @media print{
            .page-break{display: block;page-break-before: always;}
        }
    ',
]);
return $pdf->render();
```

Comment: Perfect,it works in HTML:

<div className="page-break"></div>

Answer (score 9):

From the [docs](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-breaks.html), looks like you can either use `HTML` like:

```
<pagebreak />
or
<tocpagebreak />
```

Or `PHP`:

```
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->TOCpagebreak();
```

But you already said you tried the html and din't work. [Maybe you have a parent element with float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314590/4792661)?

Comment: No, I don't have set float. <tocpagebreak /> also don't work.