# Print Page doesn't break properly on second page

Tags: html, css, laravel

I am trying out a layout in the table print preview when as I notice it doesn't break properly in the second page even though I am using `page-break-after: always;` see my code then the screen of the output below

CSS declaration

```
    div.page
          {
            page-break-after: always;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
          }
.footer{
       position:fixed;
       bottom:-10px;
       height:32px;
    }
```

The footer

```
<hr class="footer" style="width:100%;height:5px;bottom:20px;background-color:black !important;">
<div class="footer"><img width="120px" height="20px" src="/logo.png"></div>
<div class="footer" style="right:20px"></div>
<div style="left:330px" class="footer" id="dateTime"></div>
```

The table

```
 <div class="page"><!--page css here-->
    <h2 id="heading">CHEMICAL TEST</h2>
    <p id="heading">{{ $report }}</p>
    <p id="heading">Report No.: RN001</p>
    <hr>
    <center>
    <p id="heading">{{ $report }}</p>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Data Calculation</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Date</th>

    @foreach($reportData as $data)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$data['user_name']}} <br> {{$data['role_name']}}</td>
      <td>{{$data['ai_name']}}</td>
      <td>{{$data['ai_method']}}</td>
      @if($data['method_status'] == 0)
      <td>Inactive</td>
      @else
      <td>Active</td>
      @endif
      <td>{{date('m-d-Y', strtotime($data['date_axis']))}} <br> {{date('h:i A', strtotime($data['date_axis']))}} </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
    </table>
  <p id="totalresult_dtab">Total : {{$reportQuery}}</p>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

The first page is breaking correctly but after that it's not.

See the first page of the output.
[image]

Second page that is not breaking properly
[image]

Can you help me how to break it properly?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884380/css-page-break-not-working-in-all-browsers) out and see if it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use media print. write your css in @media print.

```
@media print {
       div.page
              {
                page-break-after: always;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
              }
    .footer{
           position:fixed;
           bottom:-10px;
           height:32px;
        }
    }
```