# How to define page breaks when printing html?

Tags: html, printing, report

I have a application made with Delphi 2006 which prints with QuickReport. 
Due to many bugs, I will rebuild this section of the software , generating the report in HTML and then send it to printer through some component. 
My question is, How/Can I tell when printer should break into a new page with HTML? 
Some tag or event on printing component for HTML?

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-jump-in-html-printing/1664058#answer-1664058

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can add page breaks for printing with a little bit of CSS.

CSS:

```css
@media all {
.page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
.page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

HTML:
Use a div element with the page-break class where you want insert your breaks

```html
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

Example:

```html
<div>Some content BEFORE the page break</div>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<div>Some content AFTER the page break</div>
<div class="page-break"></div>
<div> ... More content after another page break ... </div>
```

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after: "It won't apply on an empty <div> that won't generate a box."

Comment: THANK YOU. I have tried ~10 similar solutions before this and nothing was working.