# How to insert pagebreak characters into html?

Tags: html, page-break

I want to insert pagebreak characters into html text, so that if a user copies the text and pastes into MS Word or Mac Pages, the breaks are included.

**Note** I don't need these characters to have any behaviour in the html, I just need them to be included in the text copied and pasted by the user.

Is there a way to put pagebreak characters into html?

**Edit** This is not for printing, this is for copying and pasting into WYSIWYG programs, so print css will not work, it needs to be something the clipboard will transfer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I force a page jump in HTML printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-jump-in-html-printing)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Doesn't look like a dup of that question to me. To the question poster: Do you mean copying the source code (put a ^F in comments?) or copying the displayed text (dunno if it can be done)?

Comment: Not a duplicate—I want to force a page jump when pasting text into a WYSIWYG, not when printing. @KenY-N I mean copying the displayed text (although a JS "click to copy text" function could also work)