# How to split div into 2 pages when print as pdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have asp.net MVC project and want to print HTML div as pdf into two Pages and this is Example of my code
HTML Code

```
<div class="row" id="mycanvas">
<p>This is My Content1</p>
<p>This is My Content2</p>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="savePdf()">  Save As PDF </button>
```

JS Code

```
function savePdf() {
    html2canvas($("#mycanvas"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
            // generatePDF(imgData);
            generatePDF(canvas);
        }
    });
}
function generatePDF(imgData) {
    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
    var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, height);
    doc.save('download.pdf');
}
```

I Want Split this Div into 2 pdf Pages

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-jump-in-html-printing/1664058

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to split the SAME div over two pages. 
but with page breaks you should be able to put a specific div on a new page...

Something similar to this in the CSS:

```
@media print
{
  .page-break  { display:block; page-break-before:always; }

}
```

and then in the html where you want the break to happen

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

Comment: common reasons page breaks wouldn't be working is if parent elements have floats in them.  using page-break inside tables, floating elements, inline-block elements, and block elements with borders.