# When printing HTML with a PageBreak in Winforms using WebBrowser control not displaying correctly

Tags: css, winforms, webbrowser-control, page-break

I am developing a desktop application in **Windows Forms-C#**. This has a report which is shown using **WebBrowser** control.
I have generated a Report in HTML format. The report has 2 pages, Page 1-TnC and Page 2-Annexure. I have used "page-break-after" to add page-break forcefully.

```
<style> 
.forcedbreak {page-break-before: always;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
```

```
<div class="forcedbreak">
</div
><div id="pg2">
```

When output of report is displayed in Web browser, the **page-break is not shown**. If I use the as same HTML string and store as a HTML page and open in IE the page-break is displayed as expected. If I render the same HTML string as PDF, the PDF is also showing page-break as expected.
The same HTML is not rendered properly in WebBrowser control of Winform.

Can anyone help me about WebBrowser Control?

I have referred to this post also.
[Can I force a page break in HTML printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-break-in-html-printing/1664058)

Comment: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103) -- Extended features: [Web browser control emulation issue (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi, thanks! this method of FEATURE_BROWSER Worked at my end (Developer end), I have to check at the client's end.. While I have I experienced, while setting values in registry through Application gives wrong signals to Anti-Virus software. The anti-virus raises warning message about the application.

Comment: An Anti-Virus raises warnings for a Registry setting in the `CURRENT-USER` branch in relation to a Key that has no special restrictions? Do you have the same warnings setting a Key value in other sections of the Registry? If you open that Key, you'll probably find other applications registered there, for example Acrobat Reader, Fiddler etc.