# How can I prevent PDF of Google Doc from splitting row of table?

Tags: pdf, format, google-docs

I am making some Google Docs containing tables. For each table, I set the table property to prevent "Allow row to overflow across pages". It works fine in Google Docs.

However, when I download the Google Doc to PDF, some of the rows are split across pages. This can happen even if a table has only one row.

I have looked here, and couldn't find this question, although there is a related one about HTML to PDF [Prevent table cells from breaking across page when converting html to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235450/prevent-table-cells-from-breaking-across-page-when-converting-html-to-pdf).

I can't be the only one to have encountered this. Any answers please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like a bug in Google's PDF exporter, I was able to reproduce it. One workaround would be to use a different PDF exporter. Download your google doc as an ODT, open ODT in Word or LibreOffice and then save as PDF. This worked for me, the PDFs saved by both Word and LibreOffice Writer had a tall row starting from the new page, as intended.