# HTM page - page break not working while printing

Tags: html, css

I had an `htm` file. I want to add a page break to customize the page breaking place while printing. I used `@media print` for that. I tried a small demo. It is working in my google chrome  web browser. Then I used it in my complex `htm` code. but in my complex `htm` file, it is not working.

I want to break the page after the `class ="crystalstyle"`.

I used the CSS property:

```
@media print {
div.crystalstyle div  { page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-before: always; } 
}
```

when I right-click on my `htm` page and press the print button my CSS property is not working.
I attached here my `htm` file link. Please download the file and fix it or advice me to solve this.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hBhVe9V4oCBZR4-K07iFlFaAvajmwfOj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your answer already exist in page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-break-in-html-printing

Comment: In my scenario this solution not working. That is the question what I have