# Print order details using bulk action in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to build a print functionality in my Woocommerce website, I've created a button that opens a print window when clicked & it's working fine.[Woocommerce order page screenshot with 'get order details button'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEZpP.png) The problem I'm facing when I'm trying to print order's in bulk by selecting multiple order's at once, print window opens all orders in a single page [Screenshot of print window with multiple orders on same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqYWh.png) & I want to fix that, I need single order on single page so I can print orders properly.

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'add_bulk_action_print_orders' );
function add_bulk_action_print_orders( $actions ) {
   $actions['print_selected'] = __( 'Print selected orders', 'textdomain' );
   return $actions;
}
// Handle the custom bulk action
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'handle_bulk_action_print_orders', 10, 3 );
function handle_bulk_action_print_orders( $redirect_to, $action, $order_ids ) {
   if ( $action !== 'print_selected' ) {
       return $redirect_to;
   }
$order_ids = isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post'] : array();
   if ( empty( $order_ids ) ) {
       return;
   }
foreach ( $order_ids as $order_id ) {
       $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order_note = $order->get_customer_note();
$order_no = $order->get_order_number();
$order_total = $order->get_total();
$total_tax = $order->get_total_tax();
$subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();
$items=$order->get_items();

$billing_email=$order->get_billing_email();
$billing_phone=$order->get_billing_phone();

//$shipping_email = $order->get_shipping_email();
//$shipping_phone=$order->get_shipping_phone();

  $shipping_address_1 =$order->get_shipping_address_1();
$shipping_address_2 =$order->get_shipping_address_2();
$shipping_city = $order->get_shipping_city();
$shipping_state = $order->get_shipping_state();
$shipping_country = $order->get_shipping_country();
$shipping_postcode = $order->get_shipping_postcode();

  $billing_address_1 =$order->get_billing_address_1();
$billing_address_2 =$order->get_billing_address_2();
$billing_city = $order->get_billing_city();
$billing_state = $order->get_billing_state();
$billing_country = $order->get_billing_country();
$billing_postcode = $order->get_billing_postcode();
echo'<style>.my-button.clicked{background-color:yellow;}</style>';
echo'<style>body{ background-color:#fff;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>';
echo'<style> h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ margin: 0; padding: 0;} p{ margin: 0; padding: 0; } </style>';
echo'<style> .container{ width: 100%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; } .brand-section{ background-color: #b2ac88; padding: 10px 40px;} </style>'; echo'<style>.logo{ width: 50%;} .row{ display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; } .col-6{ width: 50%; flex: 0 0 auto; } .text-white{ color: #fff; } </style>';
echo'<style> .company-details{ float: right; text-align: right;} .body-section{ padding: 16px; border: 1px solid gray;} </style>';
echo'<style>.heading{ font-size: 20px; margin-bottom: 08px; } .sub-heading{ color: #262626; margin-bottom: 05px; } </style>';
echo'<style> table{ background-color: #fff; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; } </style>';
echo'<style> table thead tr{ border: 1px solid #111; background-color: #fff; } table td { vertical-align: middle !important; text-align: center; }</style>';
echo'<style> table th, table td { padding-top: 08px; padding-bottom: 08px; } .table-bordered{box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.5px gray;} </style>';
echo'<style> table-bordered td, .table-bordered th { order: 1px solid #dee2e6; } .text-right{ ext-align: end;} .w-20{ width: 20%;} </style>';
echo'<style>.float-right{float: right; }</style>';
echo'<h3>Inovice</h3>';
echo'<div class="container">';
echo '<div class="brand-section">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="col-6">';
                   echo '<h1 class="text-white">Order No.</h1>'.$order_no.'</div>';
echo '<div class="col-6">';
                   echo '<div class="company-details">';
echo '<h2 class="text-white">Oven Fresh</h2>';
                      echo '<p class="text-white">Unit No. 210 2nd floor,Mahim Industrial Estate,Off Cadel Road Mahim,Mumbai-400016 <br>GST No: 27AAUCA4280D1ZI <br> FSSAI NO:11521004000462 <br>State Name: Maharashtra, Code: 27</p>';
                      echo '<p class="text-white">+91-8080-146666</p>';
                   echo '</div>';
               echo '</div>';
           echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="body-section">';
          echo '<div class="row">';
               echo '<div class="col-6">';
                  echo '<h2 class="heading">Billing Address</h2>';  echo'<br>'.$billing_address_1.$billing_address_2.$billing_city.$billing_state.$billing_country.$billing_postcode ;
                  echo '<p class="sub-heading">Email </p>'.$billing_email;
                  echo '<p class="sub-heading">Phone </p>'.$billing_phone;
                  
             echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="col-6">';
                  echo '<h2 class="heading">Shipping Address</h2>'.$shipping_address_1.$shipping_address_2.$shipping_city.$shipping_state.$shipping_country.$shipping_postcode;
//  echo '<p class="sub-heading">Delivery Date </p>'.$delivery_date;
                //  echo '<p class="sub-heading">Time Slot</p>'.$time_slot;
  foreach ( $order->get_meta_data() as $meta ) {
if ( $meta->key === 'Delivery Date' || $meta->key === 'Time Slot' ) {
           echo '<p><strong>' . $meta->key . ':</strong> ' . $meta->value . '</p>';
       }
}
 echo '<p><strong>Customer Note :</strong>'.$order_note.'</p>';
             echo '</div>';
           echo '</div>';
       echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="body-section">';
          echo '<h3 class="heading">Ordered Items</h3>';
           echo '<br>';
           echo '<table class="table-bordered">';
               echo '<thead>';
                   echo '<tr>';
                       echo '<th>Product Name</th>';
                       echo '<th>Quantity</th>';
                       echo '<th>HSN Code</th>';
                       echo '<th>Price</th>';
echo '<th class="w-20">Grandtotal</th>';
                   echo '</tr>';
               echo '</thead>';
               echo '<tbody>';
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
$product=$item->get_product();
$product_name = $item->get_name();
$quantity= $item->get_quantity();
$price = $item->get_product()->get_regular_price();
    $hsn_code=$product->get_meta('_hsn_code');
 $grandtotal = wc_price($price * $quantity);
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$quantity.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$hsn_code.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$price.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$grandtotal.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
 }

echo'<tr>';
                      echo '<td colspan="4" class="text-right">Sub Total</td>';
                      echo '<td>'.$subtotal.'</td>';
                  echo '</tr>';
                   echo '<tr>';
                       echo '<td colspan="4" class="text-right">Tax</td>';
                       echo '<td>'.$total_tax.'</td>';
                   echo '</tr>';
                   echo '<tr>';
                       echo'<td colspan="4" class="text-right">Total</td>';
                       echo'<td>'.$order_total.'</td>';
                   echo'</tr>';
echo'</tbody>';
           echo '</table>';
echo '<div>';
           echo '<p>Footer </p>';
       echo '</div>';      
echo '</div>';
}
}
```

I'm using the code mentioned above, is there something missing or am I doing something wrong here. I need you guys help to solve this as soon as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Since this is html - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-break-in-html-printing