# javascript - wysiwyg editor page separation

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I am writing a wysiwyg editor where the user can create a report and print.  So far my editor is one continuously scrolling div.  I would like to separate that div into "pages" visibly as the user types in the report.  I am trying to stay away from commercial solutions.

Is there a way to crawl through the document an insert a break (a separation line or something) when the scroll position gets to a certain number of px?

Comment: How are you doing the printing? If you don't control this yourself already, I doubt you can display a line at the right position

Comment: This might get you on track: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664049/can-i-force-a-page-break-in-html-printing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.